# Is there a projectile speed difference in genji's left click vs right click?

Tags: overwatch

It appears that the very initial star that hits from right click is faster than that of the left click. 
Is this true?

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that the fire rate (so not the projectile speed) was different at one stage. The right click fired faster and I still think that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

[This guy](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20745194627) says he tested the projectile speeds and states the shurikens are thrown at 50 m/s - which implies both shuriken throws are done at the same speed.

More information obtained. Someone made a [google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WTUCVg9wzQGbfXi_2CtKpe4Juh57pVaXnkN1pRHgjz8/edit#gid=1521377263) detailing many aspects of the game, one of them being projectile speeds.

He lists Genji's shurikens (so assuming both fires tested) at **47 m/s**.
Assuming both tested and they are the same because he lists alt fires for other heroes such as roadhog.

This is the [original thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4oygv4/projectile_speed_chart/) it came from, but the sheet was trashed, so the linked one is a recovered version.

Comment: Found projectile speed facts and removed dps information. He also talks about how the speed vs distance works with regards to moving enemies and hitboxes but I won't write that in.

Comment: Removed the downvote since you're answering the question now. I don't think there's actually much evidence that he checked for separate speeds, though.